# system-config-kickstart has no installation candidate in Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04

I am trying to install `system-config-kickstart` on my Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop amd64. But the  package is not found. How should I install `system-config-kickstart` on Ubuntu 20.04?

I have enabled `main`, `universe`, `restricted` and `multiverse` repositories and run `apt update` before trying to install it. 
Also tried installation from `apt-get install system-config-kickstart`.

Tried searching for the package through `apt-cache search` and `apt search` but no results.

Below is the output I get when I tried installing.

```
waqas@waqas-pc:~$ sudo apt  install system-config-kickstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package system-config-kickstart is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'system-config-kickstart' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 2):

The package was removed [after](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=system-config-kickstart) 19.10 because Python 2 deprecation, but you can still get and install it manually:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/sck

cd ~/Downloads/sck

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/system-config-kickstart/system-config-kickstart_2.5.20-0ubuntu25_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

and enjoy.